# How to set a picture on a Gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

How can i set a Picture to the centre of a gridPane at the moment I generate first a random Labyrinth and set on top of the Labyrinth a Circle Shape

here is the generation Code:

```
    //add the pictures to the gridpane
    for (int j = 2; j < 7; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 2; k < 7; k++)
        {
            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(21);
            imageField = new HBox();
            Image im =new Image(zahlenplaettchenName.get(randomNumber));
            imageField.getChildren().add(new ImageView(new Image(zahlenplaettchenName.get(randomNumber),30,30,false,false)));
            if(gridpane != null){
                gridpane.add(imageField, j, k);
            }
        }
    }

}


//add the pictures to the pane 
private void fillPictureList(){
    pictureName.add("/images/Eck-Kreuzung-links-oben.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/Eck-Kreuzung-links-unten.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/Eck-Kreuzung-rechts-oben.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/Eck-Kreuzung-rechts-unten.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/Gerade-horizontal.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/T-Kreuzung-oben.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/T-Kreuzung-rechts.png");
    pictureName.add("/images/T-Kreuzung-unten.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/Gerade-vertikal.PNG");
    pictureName.add("/images/T-Kreuzung-links.PNG");

    for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++)
        {
            int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(10);
            imageField = new HBox();
            imageField.getChildren().add(new ImageView(new Image(pictureName.get(randomNumber))));
            if(gridpane != null){
                        gridpane.add(imageField, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this the Picture looks like this:

[image]

How can I centre the circleShapes ?

Comment: I rather suggest you use a simple Pane and calculate the tile positions. Then you are free to do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this to center your elements in each cell.

`imageField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the individual alignments of the nodes within their cells using `GridPane.setHalignment(circle, HPos.CENTER)` and `GridPane.setValignment(circle, VPos.CENTER)`.

You could also do it on a row or column basis using row and column constraints.